# how to get id, name and table in stream() api

Tags: java, spring, java-stream

I have a string as below:

```
@AB{id} in (select @AC{id} from @AC{table} where @AC{name}='Kavita')
```

I need to get all attributes inside curly braces i.e. id, table, name etc.

Can anyone please suggest how to do that? thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a regular expression like this: `\{(\w+)\}` to detect non-empty sequences of letters/digits/underscores between the curly braces, or `\{([A-Za-z]+)\}` if the attributes contain *only* English letters.

Then starting from Java 9, class `Matcher` has a method [`results`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--) returning `Stream<MatchResult>` and the attributes can be retrieved from `group(1)` of the mentioned regular expression:

```java
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\{(\\w+)\\}");
        
String code = "@AB{id} in (select @AC{id} from @AC{table} where @AC{name}='Kavita')";
        
List<String> parts = pat.matcher(code)
                        .results().map(mr -> mr.group(1))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(parts);
```

Output:

```
[id, id, table, name]
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply..can you please suggest the below: